# Django -- Updating specific values in a resulting queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

What is wrong in these lines:

```
for i in message_list:
    message_stream = Messages.objects.filter(OrderID = i.OrderID).order_by('-MessageLocalID')
    if message_stream[0].MessageTypeName != 'MessageAck':
        message_stream[0].status = message_stream[0].MessageTypeName
        message_stream[0].save()
```

The `status` field doesn't get saved here in the DB. What I do misunderstand here?

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace?

Comment: it doesn't show errors. only errors show when I use update method instead of save, like this: `message_stream[0].update(status = Message_stream[0].MessageTypeName)`. Please let me know if I can clarify anything more :)

Comment: You have to use `get` not `filter`.

Comment: Django docs:'Note that there is a difference between using get(), and using filter() with a slice of [0]. If there are no results that match the query, get() will raise a DoesNotExist exception.'

Comment: Agreed, but what if I want to get more than one value, which necessitates the use of filter, to make some modifications and save them to DB, would that be possible?

Comment: Of course but I'd close in on the error. Either by using `get` or some other mechanism to understand what actually is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just found the problem, please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the DB itself, the status field, where it should be updated with new values,wasn't able to receive values more than 2 characters. I used Django DB migration and extended the status field, solved the problem.

This command worked like a charm with no problems:

```
NpMessages.objects.filter(NPOrderID = i.NPOrderID, MessageTypeName = 'Request').update(status = message_stream[1].MessageTypeName)
```

and get rid of the save statement, as it didn't work eitherway!!!

Comment: You should install a PEP-8 checker. It's very hard reading your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll consider that :)